# Cannot add or update a child row .cant insert data

Tags: php, mysql

cant up date a child raw in my sql
 i created the tabels like this :

```
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// 
//create the genre table 
$genre = @mysql_query(    'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS genre (

                                                   genreName       CHAR(15),
                                                    rated       CHAR(9),

                                                   PRIMARY KEY (genreName))


                            ENGINE innoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;');  

if (!$genre) {  
  exit('<p>Error creating the genre table<br />'.  
      'Error: ' . mysql_error() . '</p>');  
} 
if ($genre) {  
  echo 'everything went just fine with genre table <br>';
}
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// 
//create the film table 
$film = @mysql_query(    'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS film (
                                                    filmID           INT(9) auto_increment , 
                                                    filmName          CHAR(30), 
                                                    year              INT(4),
                                                    genreName       CHAR(15),
                                                CONSTRAINT  FOREIGN KEY (genreName) REFERENCES genre(genreName)ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE, 

                                                   PRIMARY KEY (filmID))


                            ENGINE innoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;');  

if (!$film) {  
  exit('<p>Error creating the film table<br />'.  
      'Error: ' . mysql_error() . '</p>');  
} 
if ($film) {  
  echo 'everything went just fine with film table <br>'; }
```

and the tryed to insert data like this:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO film (filmName,year,genreName)
VALUES ('The Avengers', '2012','action')";
```

and got this eror: Error: INSERT INTO film (filmName,year,genreName) VALUES ('The Avengers', '2012','action')
Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`osherbi`.`film`, CONSTRAINT `film_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`genreName`) REFERENCES `genre` (`genreName`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)

Comment: $sql = "INSERT INTO genre (genreName, rated)
VALUES ('comedy', '8+')";
$sql = "INSERT INTO genre (genreName, rated)
VALUES ('action', '13+')";
$sql = "INSERT INTO genre (genreName, rated)
VALUES ('crime', '17+')";
$sql = "INSERT INTO genre (genreName, rated)
VALUES ('horror', '17+')";
$sql = "INSERT INTO genre (genreName, rated)
VALUES ('mystery', '8+')";
$sql = "INSERT INTO genre (genreName, rated)
VALUES ('science fiction', '8+')";
$sql = "INSERT INTO genre (genreName, rated)
VALUES ('erotica', '18+')";
$sql = "INSERT INTO genre (genreName, rated)
VALUES ('animation', 'all')";

Comment: We all know you have the drive to write many characters on your keyboard, but you may want to read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting to also format it nice

Answer (score 0):

I just made a table with your posts and got the code to work. Try this out.

Table structure for table `film` :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `film` (
`filmID` int(9) NOT NULL,
  `filmName` char(30) NOT NULL,
  `year` int(6) NOT NULL,
  `genreName` char(15) NOT NULL
)
```

Table structure for table `genre` :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `genre` (
  `genreName` char(15) NOT NULL,
  `rated` char(9) NOT NULL
)
```

Indexes for table `film` :

```
ALTER TABLE `film`
 ADD PRIMARY KEY (`filmID`), ADD KEY `genreName` (`genreName`);
```

Indexes for table `genre` :

```
ALTER TABLE `genre`
 ADD PRIMARY KEY (`genreName`);
```

Constraints for table `film` :

```
ALTER TABLE `film`
ADD CONSTRAINT `film_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`genreName`) REFERENCES `genre` (`genreName`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

**NOTE :**

To insert the data, first you need to insert the data to `genre` table. If you didn't fill up anything in `genre` table, you fill face error when you insert data to `film` table since a column `genreName` is a Foreign key that referencing to `genre` table `genreName` column which was initially null.

Add data to `genre` table like,

```
INSERT INTO `test1`.`genre` (`genreName`, `rated`) VALUES ('action', '5');
```

Then, for `film` table,

```
INSERT INTO `test1`.`film` (`filmID`, `filmName`, `year`, `genreName`) VALUES ('1', 'The Avengers', '2012', 'action');
```

I just tested it out. It's working. Good luck!